Azure Pipeline QUEUE timeout
I wonder if there is a way to define/configure/code an on-premise Azure DevOps Build Pipeline (classic or yaml) to get out of the queue if it is sitting there for too long.
I've only been able to find execution timeouts, which is NOT what I mean.
Reason is, sometimes we get outages, and lots of "nightly builds" get stuck waiting for available build agents. Since the build pipelines take a long time to execute, it has the effect of cluttering the build agents with useless late builds when they comes online again.
For this reason we have the need to set a QUEUE TIMEOUT, which cancels the execution of the Azure Pipeline after ~4 hours of waiting for an available agent. Otherwise we must individually cancel the execution of all these builds, and manually enqueue the ones which are really important.
Is this feature so far available for Azure DevOps Server 2022? Can this be done with a simple Azure DevOps Server setting, or should it be set in the pipeline definition somewhere? Is there any workaround for this issue?

Since you are using Azure DevOps Server, which doesn't require you to purchase parallel jobs, would you consider configuring more agents in the pool to be consumed by your pipelines?

I am afraid there is no build-in functionality as of now to set timeout for queue time and cancel a build/release.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I can not guarantee that any spare builds agents won't go offline too.

I am afraid that there is no built-in functionality to set and check agent job queue time. You could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
